# Selenium IDE test try-catch

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I'm recording Selenium test with Selenium IDE.

If I write a test for Selenium in Java native i can insert try-catch statement.

**Is it possibile insert try-catch statement in HTML-like test format record with Selenium IDE?**

Thanks!

Tommaso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot catch exceptions in Selenium IDE.  You would need to use Selenium RC to catch and handle exceptions.

Comment: Its possible translate automatically test made with Selenium IDE in Selenium RC?

Comment: I'd appreciate you marking this answer as accepted, if it truly answered your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You CAN do Try/Catch with the IDE now: I'm trying out SelBlocks and finding some success with it. It provides Selenium commands for javascript-like conditionals, looping, callable functions, error catching, and JSON/XML driven parameterization. It's worth a try.

SelBlocks adds a lot of useful functionality to the Selenium IDE.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/versions/

And some documentation:
http://refactoror.wikia.com/wiki/Selblocks_Reference

Comment: both links are dead now :-(

Comment: Try https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/ and https://github.com/refactoror/SelBlocks

Comment: Thanks, but SelBlocks seems abandoned. Links to Firefox addons page for SelBlocks and SelBench are not working too.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Ide does not support Try catch statement

Selenium ide HTML code convert into java code then add try catch statement into the code and run code with selenium webdriver or  Selenium RC

If you want to use Try catch statement you have to use selenium RC and Selenium webdriver.